# Inline Editing in List in Sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want to perform inline editing when I click on button then it activate textfield for title and numberfield for duration.How can it be achieve as I am new in Sencha.

```
{
            xtype: 'list',
            store: "Plays",
            itemId:"playsList",

            mode: 'MULTI',
            loadingText: "Loading PlaysList...",
            emptyText: '<div class="notes-list-empty-text">No PlayList found.</div>',
            itemTpl: '<div class="list"><div class="list-item-title">{title}</div><div class="list-item-narrative">{duration}</div><div class="list-item-hide">{hidden}</div></div>',      
            grouped: true,


        },
     {
                xtype: "button",
                iconCls: "inlineedit",
                iconMask: true,
                itemId: "inlineediting"
        },
```

So when I click on button it activate or have editing feature at list for title textfield and for duration numberfield.

Comment: Should it set the 'edit mode' to all the items of the list ?

Comment: @TDeBailleul Yes so that when I clik on button it will convert to textfield and numberfield so this method works in all list.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be to do something like this :

**Add a `editing` field to you model**

```
fields: [
    ... // Other fields
    {name:"editing", type:"boolean", defaultValue: false}, 
]
```

**Use this kind of template**

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl if="editing == false">',
        '<input type="text" name="title" value="{title}" disabled/>',
    '<tpl else>',
        '<input type="text" name="title" value="{title}"/>',
    '</tpl>'
)
```

Then when you click on the button, you need to follow these steps :

- Get your store
- Loop through all the records of the store
- For each records, set the `editing` value to true

Then the template will re-render and the inputs will be editable.

Of course you need to do work on the CSS to hide to the user that it's an input.

Finally, when the editing is done (I presume you will have some sort of 'Done' button), you need to go through all the items of your list and update the store with their new values.

I haven't tried it but I've done things similar in the past.

Hope this helps

Comment: @TDeBaileul  Now my textbox render below the list mean I didn't see the input box to be render at same item place